# MAUI Can't load images from android device

Tags: maui, filepicker

I implemented the file picker as described here:
[learn.microsoft.com/...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-picker?tabs=android)

When I open the android explorer, all files (jpg + png) are greyed-out / not accessible.

The important parts of my app you'll find below.

Tested on Android Pixel 5, Android 13 device.

**Why I can't pick a image file from Android device?**

AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
```

Code:

```
private static PickOptions GetPickOptions()
{
   var customFileType = new FilePickerFileType(
       new Dictionary<DevicePlatform, IEnumerable<string>>
       {
           { DevicePlatform.iOS, new[] { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png" } },
           { DevicePlatform.Android, new[] { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png" } },
           { DevicePlatform.WinUI, new[] { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png" } },
           { DevicePlatform.macOS, new[] { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png" } }
       });

   PickOptions options = new()
   {
       PickerTitle = AppResources.Bitte_waehlen_Sie_ein_Bild,
       FileTypes = customFileType
   };

   return options;
}

public async Task<FileResult?> PickAndShow(PickOptions options)
{
   try
   {
       var result = await FilePicker.Default.PickAsync(options);

       if (result == null)
       {
           return result;
       }

       if (!result.FileName.EndsWith("jpg", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
           !result.FileName.EndsWith("jpeg", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
           !result.FileName.EndsWith("png", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
       {
           ImageInformation = AppResources.Das_Dateiformat_wird_nicht_unterstuetzt;

           return result;
       }

       Image = result.FullPath;
       var length = new FileInfo(result.FullPath).Length;

       if (length > MaxFileSize)
       {
           ImageInformation = AppResources.Die_Datei_ueberschreitet_die_erlaubt_Groesse;

           return null;
       }

       ImageInformation = AppResources.Vielen_Dank_fuer_Ihr_Bild;

       return result;
   }
   catch (Exception)
   {
       ImageInformation = AppResources.Es_tut_uns_leid_beim_Upload_ist_ein_Fehler_passiert;
   }

   return null;
}
```

Comment: please read the [platform differences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-picker?tabs=android#platform-differences) docs for Android

Comment: @Jason I'm using ".jpg", ".jpeg" and ".png". That are standard Mime types, also listed at your link. (at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types.)

Comment: those are file extensions, not MIME types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much Jason!

The solution is to adjust the Mime types for Android.

```
    var customFileType = new FilePickerFileType(
        new Dictionary<DevicePlatform, IEnumerable<string>>
        {
            { DevicePlatform.iOS, new[] { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png" } },
            { DevicePlatform.Android, new[] { "image/jpeg", "image/png" } },
            { DevicePlatform.WinUI, new[] { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png" } },
            { DevicePlatform.macOS, new[] { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png" } }
        });
```

In the end I got in trouble loading images using iOS.
Therefor I changed from **FilePicker** to **MediaPicker**. It is much easier and works on Windows, Android and iOS.